# How to change report directory in karate?

Tags: api, automated-tests, karate

2 concerns mentioned below

1. Unable to change report directory of karate html reports. I tried with below snippet by using both relative and absolute path of new dir.

> ```
>  @testpathchange
>      Scenario: Test report 
>              * configure report = { dir: 'src/test/java' }
>              * print "Hello Test"
> ```

I also added this in karate-config.js

```
karate.configure('report', { dir: 'src/test/java' });
```

but report dir didn't change

2. [Updated] I noticed that for every run from ParalleRunner 'karate-summary.html' gets generated but when run using Junit5 it doesn't generate 'karate-summary.html', it only generate feature specific html
   [image]

Also, ParallelRunner doesn't generate cucumber.json file even if I use outputCucumberJson(true) in testParallel() method
[image]

> .outputCucumberJson(true)

[image]

Comment: @peter Could you please check my second point

Comment: next time please keep questions focused. I don't understand your second point. as far as I know every time you run a test, you will get that file in the directory which is `karate-reports` by default. maybe it is a bug in karate, so please follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas Sure Peter, I will explore more and If I feel something looks as a bug will try to replicate and then raise an issue from above link. For now I have updated the question.

Comment: I have added the issue here https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2230 @PeterThomas

Comment: sorry, works for me

Comment: @PeterThomas Thanks I checked your comment in the issue. But file format is txt and azure pipeline task expects .json file as an input. I will check some workaround then.

Comment: no, the format is JSON. this is working fine for many enterprise teams for years. see other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+azure